# Splash Screen Fade Animation issue

Tags: android, android-animation, fade, splash-screen

I done a `fade` animation with `three images` displayed in splash screen.I got an output successfully.

But I got a `two issue`:

1. **Time Loading:**

   - It tooks more time to load a splash screen.It needs to enter into
        the application as soon as possible.
2. **App doesn't Close:**

   - After entered into an Application.I am trying to close these app with    the help of Back Button in emulator.But It never closes an
     application.
   - It stays in an application itself.In log cats,I seen the loop 1,2 and    3 continues again and again.I can't able to close my app.
   - If I am press the Home Button,It displays a home screen but again enter into an application automatically.

**LogCat:**

I am not getting any logcat error.But you can see that logcat readings always running.It never gets stop.The loop 1,2 and 3 continuously reading in logcat.For these it never closes an application.Then If I am press the home button,home screen would be displayed.But sometimes it automatically enter into these application.

```
06-25 05:46:27.654: V/test(1842): 1
06-25 05:46:27.684: V/test(1842): 2
06-25 05:46:31.764: V/test(1842): 1
06-25 05:46:35.654: V/test(1842): 2
06-25 05:46:35.684: V/test(1842): 3
06-25 05:46:39.764: V/test(1842): 2
06-25 05:46:43.654: V/test(1842): 3
06-25 05:46:43.684: V/test(1842): 1
06-25 05:46:44.914: I/Choreographer(1842): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-25 05:46:46.524: I/ImageCache(1842): Memory cache created (size = 12288)
06-25 05:46:46.534: V/test1(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:46.534: V/3333333(1842): 3333333
06-25 05:46:47.334: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER1
06-25 05:46:47.434: V/test2(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:47.434: V/test3(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:47.434: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER2
06-25 05:46:47.444: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER3
06-25 05:46:47.494: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER4
06-25 05:46:47.674: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER1
06-25 05:46:47.674: V/test2(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:47.684: V/test3(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:47.684: I/ImageWorker(1842): cancelPotentialWork - cancelled work for http://tfhapp.fathershouse.in/banner-gallery/tfh-banner1-large-1.jpg
06-25 05:46:47.684: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER2
06-25 05:46:47.684: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER3
06-25 05:46:47.684: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER4
06-25 05:46:47.764: V/test(1842): 3
06-25 05:46:47.864: V/APIServiceHandler(1842): API CALLhttp://tfhapp.fathershouse.in/api/video.php
06-25 05:46:47.864: I/ImageWorker(1842): doInBackground - starting work
06-25 05:46:48.004: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER1
06-25 05:46:48.004: V/test2(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:48.014: V/test3(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:48.014: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER2
06-25 05:46:48.024: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER3
06-25 05:46:48.024: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER4
06-25 05:46:48.034: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER1
06-25 05:46:48.044: V/test2(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:48.044: V/test3(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:48.064: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER2
06-25 05:46:48.144: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER3
06-25 05:46:48.274: I/Choreographer(1842): Skipped 1086 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-25 05:46:48.674: I/ImageCache(1842): Disk cache initialized
06-25 05:46:48.854: I/Choreographer(1842): Skipped 205 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-25 05:46:49.164: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER1
06-25 05:46:49.254: V/test2(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:49.254: V/test3(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:49.264: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER2
06-25 05:46:49.324: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER3
06-25 05:46:49.324: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER4
06-25 05:46:49.374: V/####(1842): TFH BANNER1
06-25 05:46:49.434: V/test2(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:49.434: V/test3(1842): testhere
06-25 05:46:49.434: I/ImageWorker(1842): cancelPotentialWork - cancelled work for http://tfhapp.fathershouse.in/banner-gallery/tfh-banner1-large-1.jpg
```

Below I posted my entire core related to SplashActivity.

**SplashActivity.java:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    public int currentimageindex = 0;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask task;
    ImageView slidingimage;
    int count = 0;
    private int[] IMAGE_IDS = { R.drawable.spl1, R.drawable.spl2,
            R.drawable.spl3 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_splash);
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();

            }
        };

        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                count = count + 1;

                Log.v("test", count + "");
                if (count >3) {

                    Intent i=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    count=0;  
                }
            }
        }, delay, period);

    }

    //
    // public void onClick(View v) {
    //
    // finish();
    // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    // }

    /**
     * Helper method to start the animation on the splash screen
     */
    private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

        slidingimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex
                % IMAGE_IDS.length]);

        currentimageindex++;

        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.custom_anim);

        slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);

        // Log.v("test","animation slide");

    }

}
```

**layout_splash.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView3_Left"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_anim.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000">
    </alpha>
    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale=".1"
        android:fromYScale=".1"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="2000" />

</set>
```

**fade_in.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2500">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

**fade_in2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2500"
        android:startOffset="2500">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

I doesn't know how to solve these problem.Anybody can help me if you know how to solve these.Thank You.

Comment: can you explain us your requirements?

Comment: @blackbelt 1.It tooks more time in splash screen.That splash screen time have to minimise.  2.App doesn't close while pressing the back button.Always logcat reading runs the loop 1,2 and 3.

Comment: those are not your requirements. Those are your issues

Comment: @blackbelt yes I need to solve that issue. that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this code segments for solution of your problem..

```
package com.example.splashanimation;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int currentimageindex = 0;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask task;
    ImageView slidingimage;
    int count = 0;
    private int[] IMAGE_IDS = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();

            }
        };

        int delay = 500; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 4000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        final Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                count = count + 1;

                Log.v("test", count + "");
                if (count > 3) {
                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    count = 0;
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 0, period);

    }

    /**
     * Helper method to start the animation on the splash screen
     */
    private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

        slidingimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex % IMAGE_IDS.length]);

        currentimageindex++;

        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);

        slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi bro. this is stephen. need some advice.I couldn't able to chat with you in chat rooms.Because there was a issue in chat sites.So that I am contacting you here.I lost my job.now I am attended one interview.In that organization they told me we only having IEEE Student projects related to android.is it worth to work in IEEE Student projects? could you help me with your suggestion?

Comment: Yes when u have no job then do somthing for knowledge.no worry.@Naruto

Comment: @Naruto Good.All the best