# Image Auto Slider

Tags: android

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="3000" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/learn_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/learn_2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/prev_3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/prev_4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/learn_5" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

.. the images switches to the next images automatically after 3 seconds. . but i want to add some transition to it to make it more artistic.. your help is greatly appreciated.. thank you

Comment: What dis you need? in splash Activity?

Comment: nope.. just a transition when the image will switch to next image.. example the 1st image will fade when it will switch to the 2nd image,, @Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Check out these [post](http://www.techipost.com/2011/06/15/android-image-slider-with-auto-slide-code/).There you can see the four images fading one after another.There you can download the full sample code.

if you need to implement these in SplashActivity you can check out these [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405965/splash-screen-fade-animation-issue) post also.